# Check if SELECT Returns Any Rows in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a basic `SELECT` query, something like:

```
SELECT id, pname, pnumber 
FROM tableName 
WHERE pnumber IS NOT NULL
```

I'd like to then perform an `INSERT` by using the result of that `SELECT` like so:

```
IF {**the above SELECT query returned 0 rows**}
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableName (pname,pnumber) VALUES ('bob', '38499483')
END
```

My question is, how can I check for the `**the above SELECT query returned 0 rows**`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this check? If you are checking for uniqueness, a unique index on the columns is simpler

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
```

You could also do this, if you expect that the query might often return rows (especially a lot of rows), which may offer a better opportunity to short circuit:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ...)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Do nothing.';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
```

...since `IF EXISTS` will return immediately after it hits the very first row that matches.

I don't recommend using `@@ROWCOUNT` only because you will have to materialize (and ignore) the full result set every time.

Comment: I like this. Often low-tech solutions are good because they are not environment-specific. SQL code is often ported from SQL Server to MySQL to Oracle, etc...

Comment: In MySQL 5.7.15 refuses to do that: it looks like the IF EXISTS (SELECT ...) causes a permanent syntax error while trying to save the stored procedure. In fact returns: Syntax error near BEGIN... In MySQL stored procedure IF statement requires IF() THEN ... ELSE ... END IF; Isn't it?

Comment: @PowerEngineering the question isn’t about MySQL, it’s about Microsoft SQL Server. Is this confusion why you down-voted?

Answer (score 8):

In MySQL you can check the number of rows returned from last SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: Nice, this is a better solution in many cases. In my case I wanted to not only check if the item exists but also select it and use it for some later operations.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
SELECT id, pname, pnumber 
FROM tableName 
WHERE pnumber IS NOT NULL
```

after this select ask for `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
```

In this way you can return some data and check if that had results or no

Answer (score 2):

Code is :

```
EXEC(SELECT * FROM Table_Name)
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT>1)    --@@ROWCOUNT is the count number of return's rows
    BEGIN
       // code here
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people have design pattern issues with this logic.

1 - Test existence of record.
2 - If it does not exist, insert the record.

Especially if concurrency comes into play.  Depending upon isolation level, you might have duplicate data or key violations.

Why not place a primary key on pname and pnumber in the first place.  I am assuming you are talking about a person table.

My example.

```
--
-- Setup sample table w/data
--

-- Sample table
create table #person
( 
    person_id int identity (1, 1),
    person_name varchar(64) not null,
    person_no varchar(16) not null
);
go

-- primary key
alter table #person 
   add primary key (person_no, person_name)
go

-- first insert works
insert into #person (person_name, person_no) values ('bilbo', 123)
go
```

The key to the solution is to trap the primary key violation.  Ignoring this error might be a good or bad depending upon your business logic.

I am deciding to ignore the issue.

```
-- 
-- Ignore primary key violations
--

-- Try these steps
BEGIN TRY

    -- Second insert fails
    insert into #person (person_name, person_no) values ('bilbo', 123)

END TRY

-- Error Handler
BEGIN CATCH

    -- Ignore PK error
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
       ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
       ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
       ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
       ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

This solution eliminates duplicate entries and does not report PK violations.

Comment: I was trying to ONLY perform an INSERT if it didn't exist because I was running into a postback issue in ASP.NET. So the record existing meant that it didn't need to be inserted because it was already logged. With that said, I will take your answer into account in the upcoming design changes. Thanks.

Comment: I have a Microsoft product on one of my servers that is doing the same logic.  If exists, then return key otherwise, insert with update lock.  I am constantly getting deadlock notifications in my SQL Sentry Monitoring system.  The solution I proposed was the above, but they have not implemented it yet!