# Why do I get wrong submission of my query?

Tags: t-sql

For an assignment I have to do the following.

Write a script that safely checks whether a certain region exists:

Declare a custom region `@region` called `Space`, of type `NVARCHAR(25)`.
Use `IF NOT EXISTS, ELSE, and BEGIN..END` to:

throw an error with `THROW 50001, 'Error!', 0` if no record whose RegionDescription matches `@region` exists.
select all columns for that region from the Region table if the record does exist.
Notes:

Specify the Region table as `Region`, not `dbo.Region`.
Use `SELECT * FROM Region <fill in>` everywhere.

The query that I wrote is somehow not correct, but I do not know what is wrong:

```
DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(25)='Space'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Region WHERE RegionDescription = @region)
BEGIN
  THROW 50001, 'Error!', 0;
  END
ELSE 
BEGIN
(SELECT * FROM Region WHERE RegionDescription = @region)
END
```

Comment: I think you should fire whoever gave you this homework on the count of them teaching bad practices. Omitting schema qualifier is bad practice, also there's no point of using `else` after `throw` - the code will never progress after the `throw` anyway. Also, this type of query has a potential risk of someone deleting the records from the table between the two select statements. It should be wrapped in an explicit transaction with a serializable isolation level to protect from it. From what I can see, the query you wrote match the requirements perfectly, however flawed the requirements are.

Comment: Maybe it's something silly, as that you need to take it more literally? They ask if "a record exists", while you check if "a record not exists".

Comment: Your code works and looks correct based on requirement.  Not sure why they are saying it's not correct.  If they are being really picky, in your ELSE you don't need  brackets around the select, but works either way, plus maybe they don't want you using "Select *" and want the columns listed out.  Other than that, not sure.

Comment: Or maybe they expect another method? Maybe by using `@@ROWCOUNT`? Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301994/4003419)

Comment: Why do you say your query is not correct?   Be specific, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query I wrote and was successful in submission. Not sure what is different between the two....

```
DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(25)='Space'

IF NOT EXISTS (Select * From Region WHERE RegionDescription=@region)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001,'error!',0;
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
(SELECT * from Region Where RegionDescription=@region)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is correct. It outputs "Error!" because that is what it is supposed to do if the Region called "Space" does not exist in the table. Try to insert a row in the table with a RegionDescription called "Space", then your query should output that row.

Maybe the problem is simply that you do not have a table called Region. If this is true, then you should start by creating this table. The table must have some columns, of which one column should be called RegionDescription.

If this does not help you, could you please state the error message that you are getting.

Comment: Thank you. I do not get a specific error message. Just that my submission of the answer is not correct..

Comment: There is only one table named dbo.Region with two columns:
RegionID    RegionDescription
1            Eastern                                           
2            Western                                           
3            Northern                                          
4            Southern                                          
5            Space

Comment: Maybe they want you to be more explicit about the Unicode data type. You could write the first line like this: DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(25)=N'Space'

Comment: The query does not throw an error. It just shows that one row is effected.